# Stuck at looking for peers when I setup full ethereum node in Ubuntu

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumjs, geth-debugging, full-node

I am trying to install a full Ethereum 1.0 node on Ubuntu, but I keep encountering an issue. I have tried synchronizing the local time and turning off the firewall, and my computer resources are more than enough to install the full node. I have a hard drive with 1TB SSD, a CPU with 8 cores and 8GHz, 64GB of RAM, and fast internet speed.
Please help me resolve this issue.

> INFO [05-28|13:42:35.678] Looking for peers
> peercount=4 tried=38 static=0
> INFO [05-28|13:42:45.694] Looking for peers                        peercount=4 tried=36 static=0
> INFO [05-28|13:42:55.833] Looking for peers                        peercount=4 tried=41 static=0
> INFO [05-28|13:43:05.989] Looking for peers                        peercount=4 tried=40 static=0
> WARN [05-28|13:45:37.703] Post-merge network, but no beacon client has been seen. Please launch one to follow the chain!
> WARN [05-28|13:47:22.134] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=8faf3e54 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth
> support"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should sync with consensus client also to run the GETH execution client.
For example, in my case I used lighthouse beacon node to sync with GETH.
There might be several kinds of configurable settings to sync it and the two clients, execution and consensus clients are synced with the JWT. You can set it with /tmp/JWT